# Using NuGet with WIX doesn't work when building release

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution which contains a WIX project. I've added WIX via NuGet months ago, and it's version 3.8.1128.0 Everything works fine when I'm building during my development process.

When I'm ready to release, I branch the folder in SVN, and then pull the branch down to my development machine. When I open the solution in the branch, it can't open the WIX project. (It says "(load failed)" next to the project.

When I try to reload the project from VS, I get the error

> The imported project "c:\Projects\xxxxx\yyyyy\SolutionName\packages\WiX.Toolset.3.8.1128.0\tools\wix\wwix.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the < Import > declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I've tried to add the `Wix Toolset (unofficial)` NuGet package, but I only see the 3.9.1208.0 version when I go to the "Online" tab of the Manage NuGet Packages for the solution.

The goal is to get the solution which includes projects for the binary and the wix msi package onto a build server, but if I can't rely on NuGet to install WiX, I'm not sure how to go about setting this up on another machine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the the WiX Toolset NuGet package it modifies the paths to the WiX MSBuild files so that the MSBuild files are used from the NuGet package instead of from `C:\Program Files\WiX` where they are when WiX is installed on the machine. The relevant parts of the project file are shown below:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WixToolPath>$(SolutionDir)packages\WiX.Toolset.3.8.1128.0\tools\wix\    </WixToolPath>
    <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
```

Since this is a WiX project file the Import element does not have a condition that checks if the WiXTargetsPath exists so Visual Studio will fail to load the project if the Wix.targets file is missing. Unfortunately adding a condition, as shown below, whilst allowing Visual Studio to load the project does not fix the build.

```
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists($(WixTargetsPath))"/>
```

With the above condition in the project file then Visual Studio on building the project will restore the WiX NuGet package automatically, if you have a recent version of NuGet installed, but you still get a build error about a missing Build target for the WiX project. This build error can only be fixed by closing and re-opening the solution again after WiX NuGet package has been restored.

On the build server I would create a pre-build step that restores the NuGet packages using NuGet.exe restore before the WiX project is built:

```
NuGet.exe restore path\to\the\solution\yoursolution.sln
```

That will restore the WiX package. Then you can build the WiX project without any errors about missing WiX targets files.

Another way would be to check in the packages directory into source control. However that will add binaries to the source control which you may not want to do.

Also WiX.Toolset.3.8.1128.0 is available from nuget.org but the NuGet dialog will show you the latest version. You can install specific versions of NuGet packages using the Package Manager Console. When NuGet 3.0 is released you should be able to do the same thing from the NuGet dialog.

Comment: I thought the reason for using NuGet was so that you don't have to have special scripts for building on a different machine. What exactly does the NuGet package for WiX do? Is it just for VS integration?

Comment: NuGet will automatically restore NuGet packages if you build them in Visual Studio. It will not do that on a build server. For a build server you will need to run a pre-build step or use the deprecated Enable Package Restore so the packages are restored. This works for the majority of NuGe t packages. The WiX one seems to be a special case since the build targets file is used to define the project build information and does not just extend the existing targets file.

Comment: The WiX NuGet package makes the project self-contained so you do not have to install WiX separately on the machine (developer or build server).

Comment: I guess I still don't understand then. I'm not running on a build server, and yet it doesn't appear that I can simply open the solution on another machine and have NuGet handle the package updated.

Comment: In general with NuGet you can just open the solution on another machine and everything will work. The problem is with the WiX NuGet package and WiX projects. The WiX NuGet package is trying to override the WiX.targets file that is installed separately. Since this defines the project it is causing problems with Visual Studio. Other NuGet packages add custom MSBuild targets files to the project and NuGet restore will handle them without any errors. The problem is specific to the WiX NuGet package.

Comment: To be specific, this should happen with any NuGet package that defines msbuild targets for a project.  The problem is that in order to know which packages to restore, Visual Studio must load all the project files.  If the project file depends on .target files that must be installed by NuGet, the project will fail to load, but the NuGet packages will still be downloaded.  Now that the .targets files are there, the next time you start Visual Studio, it should work fine.  That's why Matt Ward suggests a 'bootstrap' script to load the NuGet packages before you start Visual Studio.

Comment: Amazing, 5 years later this solution still works!